# What is Spock's rank in "Ask Not"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, starfleet-rank, star-trek-short-treks

The short trek "Ask Not" is hard to accurately place in the timeline. Even Memory Alpha just puts the timeframe at "2250s or 2260s". However, as Spock is an ensign in "Q&A", but a lieutenant in Discovery, I was wondering what rank he holds in "Ask Not", which may help to get a rough idea of when this short was set.

As ranks in the retcon continuity are denoted by the officer's combadge rather than pips, it makes it hard to see what rank someone is. I tried to zoom in on the combadge on the version I have but it was too blurry to see, but I know there are high definition versions out there that may have captured this detail.

Comment: Ah, the controversial "Ask not, tell not" policy.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I believe it's a reference to "Ask not what your country can do for you", rather than "Don't ask, don't tell"

Comment: “Ask, or ask not. There is no spoon.” — Senator Organa

Comment: "To ask, or to ask not, there is no question."